# Abstracting boilerplate in C#

Tags: c#, interface, abstraction, boilerplate

(Using VS 2017 and .Net Framework 3.5)

Been learning c# for about 1 week, so pretty much a complete newbie.

I'm trying to move all the generic boilerplate code for a game mod I'm working on in to separate projects within a 'solution', for example I don't want the main project cluttered with code that manages the settings object. My goal is to move boilerplate stuff in separate github repos at a later date for use in other mods.

I've created an interface in a separate project that defines 'must have' features for a settings object (version number, methods to migrate and validate). I now want to create a 'manager' (or whatever the correct C# terminology is) that handles boilerplate functionality for my settings object, such as persistence to xml or current game, rendering UI to change settings, etc.

Are there any patterns for such things? For example, the project that contains boilerplate won't reference the main project where the settings object lives, but I know that object will be derived from the interface defined in the settings project. So in the 'settings manager' class, is there a way to denote that params and property values must be derived from a given interface? That way I can just pass in settings object from main project and tell the settings project what to do with it.

Comment: I am not sure if there's any design pattern for this use case, and asking for such is off-topic anyway. However, wouldn't you just want a `public class FeaturesManager { public FeaturesManager(List<IFeature> features) { } }`?

Comment: There are many ways to such things, I don't think this question will live long as it's not a terribly good question, but for your next question, try and come up with a specific problem ( with code ) .  General Advice on design isn't a good fit for SO